# почему class A<T extends Comparable<T>> а не - class A<T implements Comparable<T>>?

Tags: java, generics

`Comparable<T>` интерфейс и класс должен имплементировать интерфейс.

Например `Integer implements Comparable<Integer>`.

Почему же говорят, что `class A<T extends Comparable<T>>` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40392671/7485582

Comment: Вопрос нужно адресовать разработчикам Java)

Comment: понятно, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Потому что то что здесь `Integer implements Comparable<Integer>` вы говорите:

"Класс Integer реализует интерфейс Comparable". Это ключевое слово используется при использовании интерфейсов.

```
class A<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

В этом же куске кода говорится следующее: 
"Есть класс А в котором есть какой-то параметризированный тип. И этот тип обязан быть экземпляром Comparable", это ключевое слово из Generic Wildcards. И здесь не важно будет ли этот класс T имплементировать интерфейс или же наследоваться от какого-то класса, в отличии от extends и implements при обычном использовании.

Надеюсь, что смог хоть немного ответить на ваш вопрос. Я бы рекомендовал вам больше почитать про Generics в Java.

[Здесь](https://habr.com/ru/post/207360/) и [здесь](https://medium.com/omnius/wildcards-in-java-generics-part-1-3-dd2ce5b0e59a) можно почитать подробнее.